# upgrade of Ubuntu from 9.4 to 9.10 trashed my entire system

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, upgrade, ubuntu-9.04

I just upgraded from Ubunto 9.4 to 9.10
Since then everything went down hill:

1. Browser (fire fox 3.6) get stuck every new site I try to open
2. The entire system is sluggish
3. When I want to see a movie, all the colors are off (red became blue...). I am using nvidia.

b.t.w I would love to google it, if I knew what to google for.

Comment: Why didn't you upgrade to 10.04?

Comment: @jer.salamon  to do that I first had to upgrade to 9.10  I didm't continue due to all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

[Burn a new live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) with Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, test it on your system to make sure it's compatible, back up your files, and perform a fresh install, wiping out your old Ubuntu partition. That should clear up any problems.

Comment: might as well try first upgrading to 10.4 using the update manager, right?

Comment: @Itay, you could, but make sure you have everything backed up. In my experience, it's often better to just start clean rather than go through a migration hell :)

Answer (score 1):

You could go to NVIDIA website and manually download the driver for your video card.

But I would most certainly recommend upgrading it to version 10.04

Answer (score 1):

Though I agree w/Evan's answer (starting clean is usually easier in the long run), here are a few things you could try:

- Clean up old and out-of-date libraries.  Completely clean out your NVidia drivers and install the latest.  Remove any Firefox installations and reinstall fresh.
- Check out what services are starting up when Ubuntu initializes.  Clean out anything you don't need.  Are you running both KDE and Gnome?  When I was running both recently, I noticed KDE (which I wasn't using) had a number of extra services running (e.g. MySQL) even when I was only in Gnome.  Removing KDE helped a bit to speed things up.  Are you running Compiz?  It can be a resource hog, and if your system can't handle it, I would recommend removing it.

You mentioned your system is sluggish.  This can be a hard thing to quantify.  Are certain applications taking longer, or have you noticed the system itself responding more slowly?  If it's the latter, are you sure you have enough resources available to run the system?  If it's the former, are your applications up-to-date?  I know some of my favorite programs (e.g. Eclipse) have a track-record of poor performance.  Upgrading them usually helps.

Comment: It seems to me now that when firefox is up, then it is when the system is sluggish.

Comment: Aha, great thing to know. Have you tried running 'top' to capture memory and CPU usage for FF?  I would definitely start by reinstalling it w/no add-ons and see if system responsiveness improves.

Answer (score 0):

I would go directly for the upgrade to 10.04 from where you are and fix what need to be fixed there if still not working. When I do multiple upgrades like that, I don't even look at the intermediate stages, I only log in and start the next upgrade. I look what need fixes at the end so I have to fix only once... and I think less you modify the original config, better for the next upgrade.